# Adding and removing image Tkinter / root

Tags: python, image, tkinter, root

Below is my code. The code is from within a different program, so a button would be clicked
on another program and initiate this code.I have been struggling with this a while, in short i am trying to a) take an image, save it to a directory, b) display the image on canvas or root a long with a button named "refresh". When refresh is clicked then remove is called deleting the 'file' first taken, takes another picture and refreshes the canvas with the second picture taken and so on and on. I am not seeming to get it to work in this sequence and have used multiple examples etc etc. Can anyone assist please, is my design incorrect perhaps? I have ample other code but the code below details only one function calling global properties etc etc. I would appreciate an answer but also want to learn from the answer to understand what is being done wrong.

```
import os
import sys
import time
from VideoCapture import Device
impot Image
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter


root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Camera Capture")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.geometry("600x400")

path = ('C:\Users\Public')
os.chdir(path)

def take_picture():
    global root
    global path
    os.chdir(path)
    cam = Device()
    cam.saveSnapshot('pic.gif')
    webcam_pic = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='./pic.gif')
    item = Label(root, anchor = W, image = webcam_pic)
    item.pack()


button_take_picture = Button(root, text = "Take picture", command = take_picture(), bg    
=          'blue')
button_take_picture.place(relx = .9, rely = .5, anchor = "center")





mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the command should be without this '()'

```
command =take_picture

button_take_picture = Button(root, text = "Take picture", command = take_picture, bg=blue')
```